# asp:dropdownlist width: How to make the control narrower than the dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a web form with a dropdown list `<asp:dropdownlist>`, but for the sake of formatting I want the actual control (before you open the dropdown list) to be relatively narrow.  When the user opens the contents of the dropdown, I want the actual list to appear wider than the control.

Something like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [ibm.com](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/07/0206_bermingham/dw_ta_long.jpg))</sub>

How can you achieve this functionality with ASP.NET webforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, either the browser will expand the list width when dropped or it won't. And you guessed it IE won't.

Your only bet with IE is to set the `title` attribute of the `option` element to the value text. Then you will get a tooltip.

Answer (score 0):

Surely this is just a css issue? On the dropdownlist control you could either say width="50" or put the style tag on there style="width: 50px".
I think you may possibly always run into issues with IE 6/7 though no matter which way you do it